# Python Requests : TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a Requests program I'm trying to run but occasionally get this error message:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse(buffering=True)
TypeError: getresponse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'buffering'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 378, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 251, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 376, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 609, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 247, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 309, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 559, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 378, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1174, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 282, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\http\client.py", line 251, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\Desktop\Sineko Official Scripts\Jessie\cURL_insta_test.py", line 197, in run
    if check_account(account, request):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\Desktop\Sineko Official Scripts\Jessie\cURL_insta_test.py", line 20, in check_account
    account_url = instagram_session.get("https://instagram.com/{}".format(account))
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 480, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 576, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 426, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\Desktop\Sineko Official Scripts\Jessie\cURL_insta_test.py", line 219, in <module>
    pool.starmap(run, accounts)
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 268, in starmap
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Acer-PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

I think I understand that this is happening because I am sending too many requests at once, though it is only about ever 7 seconds, what I'd like to know is, how come this error does not say what line or what request sent is causing the error (Or maybe it does and I missed it, if so please tell me where), and I tried using a try and except for TypeError, I either put it in the wrong place or am using the wrong Error, where should I be putting the Try and Except? Around the request sent? and if so, is it a TypeError I should be looking for?

Edit : Checked the two github threads listed in the comments, the first one says to upgrade but Im already at requests 2.9 and they said its for anything above 2.7 and the second didn't seem to come to a conclusion on a fix or where to put my own try and except to catch the error, this is my code : https://github.com/Fuledbyramen/soquestion

Comment: Showing us error without code is pretty much useless.

Comment: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1915

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: Which appears to be a dupe of https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1289?

Comment: Okay fixed my question